# elephant-bird compile failure: Missing hadoop-compat/target/classes directory

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I am trying to use ElephantBird to add sequence file storage functionality to Pig. I have cloned the ElephantBird package from GitHub, but when I try to compile using `mvn package`, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project elephant-bird-hadoop-compat: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: directory not found: /Users/Johno/Downloads/elephant-bird-download/hadoop-compat/target/classes
```

I don't understand what's going on, since I have not edited the directory whatsoever. I have just followed the first 2 instructions listed under QuickStart on the [ElephantBird Readme](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird). I have checked the issue log, and it doesn't seem to be happening to other people. Why me?